# how to use apache kafka consumer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I am trying to use apache kafka consumer and producer with in laravel framework

i create console command and execute php artisan command with nohup in production to be run until exeption happen. is there any best way to use real time consume and pruduce and prevent message loss
and if i kill command with kill pid messages will be loss ?

```
class JsonKafka extends Command
{

    private $topic;


    private $producer;

    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'kafka:up';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'kafka';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();
        $conf->set('metadata.broker.list', '0.0.0.0:29092');
        //$conf->set('enable.idempotence', 'true');
        $this->producer = new \RdKafka\Producer($conf);
        $this->topic = $this->producer->newTopic('test_php');

    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //consume
        $conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();
        // Set a rebalance callback to log partition assignments (optional)
        $conf->setRebalanceCb(function (\RdKafka\KafkaConsumer $kafka, $err, array $partitions = null) {
            switch ($err) {
                case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__ASSIGN_PARTITIONS:
                    echo "Assign: ";
                    var_dump($partitions);
                    $kafka->assign($partitions);
                    break;

                case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__REVOKE_PARTITIONS:
                    echo "Revoke: ";
                    var_dump($partitions);
                    $kafka->assign(NULL);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new \Exception($err);
            }
        });
        // Configure the group.id. All consumer with the same group.id will consume
        // different partitions.
        $conf->set('group.id', 'service');
        // Initial list of Kafka brokers
        $conf->set('metadata.broker.list', '0.0.0.0:29092');
        // Set where to start consuming messages when there is no initial offset in
        // offset store or the desired offset is out of range.
        // 'earliest': start from the beginning
        $conf->set('auto.offset.reset', 'earliest');
        $consumer = new \RdKafka\KafkaConsumer($conf);
        // Subscribe to topic 'messages'
        $consumer->subscribe(['messages']);
        echo "Waiting for partition assignment... (make take some time when\n";
        echo "quickly re-joining the group after leaving it.)\n";
        while (true) {
            $message = $consumer->consume(120 * 1000);

            switch ($message->err) {
                case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR:
               Service::getInstance()->main(json_decode($message->payload, true))                    
                    break;
                case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__PARTITION_EOF:
                    echo "No more messages; will wait for more\n";
                    break;
                case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__TIMED_OUT:
                    echo "Timed out\n";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new \Exception($message->errstr(), $message->err);
            }
        }
    }

    private function produce(string $key,array $message)
    {
        $this->topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, json_encode($message), $key);
        $this->producer->poll(0);
        for ($flushRetries = 0; $flushRetries < 10; $flushRetries++) {
            $result = $this->producer->flush(10000);
            if (RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR === $result) {
                echo 'produced' . PHP_EOL;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR !== $result) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Was unable to flush, messages might be lost!');
        }

    }
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working with this code?

Comment: it is working ok but i want to know if i want to stop it with kill process id messages will be lost ? or any way in this code to make massages lost i mostly looking for suggestions

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "lost". Consuming data from Kafka doesn't remove it from the topics like other message brokers. If you restart the consumer, it'll continue reading from the last committed offset

Comment: ok but i want to to know if massage consumedand in the right time something happens and massage not saved into db also what about producing

Comment: If a consumed event is not saved in the database, you shouldn't commit the record. Then, if/when the consumer restarts, it'll try again because the record is still in the topic to be consumed... For producers, if your app crashes, the records are dropped,  along with any other in-memory data structures; that's not unique to Kafka.